# correct syntax for an xslt transform

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-3.5, xslt

here is my code, I am getting an error when I try and parse my xml and xslt file- however I just want to know if my syntax/ code is correct for the transform. I am getting an exception with something like - Page\r\n

Using Visual studio when I manaully test the xslt transform everything works...

```
var XslFo = XElementPassedInAsAParamOrSomething;

                //load the xsl
                XslCompiledTransform xslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
                using (XmlReader reader = XslFo.CreateReader())
                {
                    xslTrans.Load(reader);
                }

                //create the output stream
                MemoryStream result = new MemoryStream();

                //do the actual transform of xml
                using (XmlReader reader = XmlData.CreateReader())
                {
                    xslTrans.Transform(reader, null, result);
                }

                //return result as XElement (for dumping  db etc)
                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(result))
                {
                    return XElement.Load(reader);
                }
```

NOTE: My exception is "Root Element is missing".

EDIT: Thanks Dimitri - I will need to check your code, however just for clarity I think it is best I provide my code:

I am loading both my Xmls via Embedded resourse (if that does make any difference)

Xml:

```
    <html>   
<head>
        <title>Spanish Review Handbook</title>   
</head>   
<body>
        <h3>Introduction</h3>
        <p>
          This handbook covers the major topics in Spanish, but is by
          no means complete.
        </p>   
</body> 
</html>
```

Xsl:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                    version="1.0">

      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:variable name="pagewidth" select="21.5"/>
      <xsl:variable name="bodywidth" select="19"/>
      <xsl:template match="html">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="leftPage"
          page-height="27.9cm"
          page-width="{$pagewidth}cm"
          margin-left="1cm"
          margin-right="2cm"
          margin-top="1cm"
          margin-bottom="1cm">
          <fo:region-before extent="1cm"/>
          <fo:region-after extent="1cm"/>
          <fo:region-body
            margin-top="1cm"
            margin-bottom="1cm" />
        </fo:simple-page-master>

        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="rightPage"
          page-height="27.9cm"
          page-width="{$pagewidth}cm"
          margin-left="2cm"
          margin-right="1cm"
          margin-top="0.5cm"
          margin-bottom="0.5cm">
          <fo:region-before extent="1cm"/>
          <fo:region-after extent="1cm"/>
          <fo:region-body
            margin-top="1cm"
            margin-bottom="1cm" />
        </fo:simple-page-master>

        <!-- Set up the sequence of pages -->
        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="contents">
          <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference
              master-name="leftPage"
              odd-or-even="odd"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference
              master-name="rightPage"
              odd-or-even="even"/>
          </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        </fo:page-sequence-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>

      <fo:page-sequence master-name="contents" initial-page-number="1">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:flow>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h3">
    <fo:block font-size="14pt" font-weight="bold"
      space-before="6pt">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <fo:block text-indent="1em"
      space-before="4pt" space-after="4pt">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b">
    <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:inline>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="i">
    <fo:inline font-style="italic">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:inline>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Very nice. Now what was it you wanted to know?

Comment: the correct syntax for an xslt transform... I have shown a sample of my code but I get some weird Page\r\n is not recognized exception

Comment: Do you get an exception or a compiler error? Could you paste the exact text of exception\error you get?

Comment: I am not too concerned with the exception just yet, I want to verify if my code is correct first, any ideas?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of the error. Also this answer points out the three places where such error can happen and also outlines the most probable place in the code where this usually happens.

Comment: "I am not too concerned with the exception just yet, I want to verify if my code is correct first, any ideas?" You should be concerned with the exception. It tells you what's wrong. It's like if you take your car into a garage and tell them it doesn't work, they will ask you how it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The exception clearly tells you the reason of the problem**: "Root Element is missing".

This means that you are trying to parse as XML something that doesn't have a top element (probably has more than one elements at the top level).

This can happen at three places in your code (not possible to say which, because you havent provided neither the source XML document, nor the XSLT stylesheet(s), nor the result of the transformation):

Here (the xslt stylesheet may lack a top element):

```
using (XmlReader reader = XslFo.CreateReader())                 
{                     
  xslTrans.Load(reader);                 
}
```

Here (the XML source may lack a top element):

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlData.CreateReader())                    
{                        
  xslTrans.Transform(reader, null, result);                    
}
```

And here (the result of the transformation may lack a top element):

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(result))                     
{                         
  return XElement.Load(reader);                     
}
```

Based from my experience, it is highly probable that the error happens at the last code snippet.

Comment: I have added the relevant code: yes, the error is only thrown on the last instance when I try to return an instance of XElement, therefore I cannot tell if I have a root node element or not...

Comment: FYI: When I hover over the 3rd part 'XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(result)' the variable reader is {None} with a dept of 0 and no attributes, I guess it is not being read at all?